# c++ how to properly declare friend class method of another class

Tags: c++, friend, friend-function

consider the following example.

```
class A
{
    int member;
};

class B
{
    A& a_ref;
    void manipulate()
    {
        a_ref.member++;
    }
};
```

Now, obviously, `B::manipulate` can not access `a_ref`. I would like to allow (only) `class B` to get (reference) to `A::member`. I know that there exists `friend` keyword, but I do not know how to use it properly. My intention is, that I could change `B::manipulate` implementation to become this

```
int& A::only_B_can_call_this() // become friend of B somehow
{
    return member;
}

void B::manipulate()
{
    a_ref.only_B_can_call_this()++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make `B` a friend:

```
class A
{
    int member;
    friend /*class*/ B;  // class is optional, required if B isn't declared yet
};
```

Note that `friend`s are anti-patterns - if something is `private`, it probably shouldn't be accessed. What are you trying to accomplish? Why isn't A self-contained? Why does another class need to access its internal data?

Use friend if you have valid answers/reasons for these questions.

Comment: Thanks, so I have to make whole A available to B? I could not make just one function available to B?

Comment: Also, does accessibility specifier of friendness matter? So, does it matter if `friend` is declared in `public:`/`private:`/`protected:` section?

Comment: Yes (whole class is friend) and no (the section doesn't matter).

Answer (score 2):

You simply add `friend class <class_name>;` to the class that wants to make its members accessible, where `<class_name>` is the name of the class that you want to provide access for.

```
class A
{
    friend class B; // allow class B to access private members of A
    int member;
};

class B
{
    A& a_ref;
    void manipulate()
    {
        a_ref.member++;
    }
};
```

Comment: And could I make just one function available to `B`? Also, does accessibility specifier of friendness matter? So, does it matter if `friend` is declared in `public:`/`private:`/`protected:` section?